# Get ID of clicked Element in snap.svg

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

What is the best (cross browser) approach to get the attribute `id` (or basically any attribute that helps me identifying the Element on which the event happened) within an event handling function (e.g. click callback function) of **snap.svg** http://snapsvg.io/

Here is some code. What I have tried seems to work in latest Chrome and FF, but I wonder if there is a better approach.

```
    //add an Element, set id
    var mySvg = Snap('#mySvg');
    var myRect = mySvg.rect(10,10,200,100);
    myRect.attr({id:'myId'});

    //register click callback
    myRect.click(clickCallback);

    //click callback
    var clickCallback = function(event) {
       // how do I get the id of the clicked element?
       // is this cross browser valid?
       var id = event.target.attributes.id.nodeValue;
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's an issue with the current version of Snap and id, which is fixed in next release (0.2 which may be current by now) https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/166 so worth a read at some point.

However, I typically don't use an id like that for these cases, I would use 'this'. So with a handler, it can look something like...

```
var mySvg = Snap(400, 620);
var myRect = mySvg.rect(10,10,200,100);

var clickCallback = function(event) {
    this.attr({ fill: 'blue' });
};

myRect.click(clickCallback);
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qgTdF/2/

This solution may work for you, and be preferable, but it depends ultimately if you need to do something else (in which case maybe post another question with the specific issue). It may also be worth trying the latest version (I think 0.2), if you need to fiddle a bit and specifically use the id.

Comment: Snap 0.2 is the version i'm working with, so this should not be a problem anymore. Thanks for mentioning the _this_ reference. this.attr('id'); inside the callback function got me the ID of the rect. So that works. I also tried to use an argument when setting the clickCallback-function like myRect.click(clickCallback,'someArgument'); In that case the _this_ reference inside the callback function refered to 'someArgument'. Don't know if this is intended behaviour.

Comment: Yes, this is intended. So you can set the context of what you want 'this' to have. So you may typically do it like this, to make the circle change instead.... http://jsfiddle.net/qgTdF/3/

Comment: Note, if you want to pass args and change the this context, you could do something like the following... http://jsfiddle.net/qgTdF/4/ Not a lot of advantage here, but it could be useful at some point.

Comment: good to know, may come in handy at some point. accepting your answer, thanks for your help.

Comment: although this question is already answered, this should be pointed out as well: Snap Elements have a [.data method](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.data) for setting key/value pairs. So on creation of an Element like a rect, it is easy to set some custom data like `myRect.data('myId',999);` later in a (click)callback function you can get it with `var id = this.data('myId');`

Comment: I prefer to never use `this` with changed context. I always use arrow functions and deem such behavior of `this` as plain wrong. If you feel the same you can use `event.target` instead of `this`, where `event` is the function's parameter. And no need to keep the context switching in mind.

Comment: However, this wouldn't be right for most peoples cases. Mostly they want the element the handler was added to, not the target (sure sometimes you want the target, but it's not a case of preference, it's a case of which is the exact thing you want, and mostly it would be the element the handler was applied to, not the target).